# DirectX UV Coordinates not responding?

Tags: c++, directx

My UV coordinates never respond to me for some reason. It is just UV mapping itself in the smallest way possible. It's a tile-able texture and the program is subdividing so much I can't even zoom in and see it right. It just looks like lots of noise. So I set my UV coordinates to 0 and 0 for every vertex and it ignored and mapped the same way still. I continuously just changed the coordinates and I'm not getting any results.

Shader:
http://gyazo.com/0422d4f37134671eb0b35c2a00605f7e

Declaration:

```
    D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 Decl[] =
    {
        {
            0,
            0,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION,
            0
        },
        {
            0,
            0,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,
            0
        },
        D3DDECL_END()
    };
```

My Vertice UV:

```
                Vertices[y * WIDTH + x].V = y / 1.28;
                Vertices[y * WIDTH + x].U = x / 1.28;
```

My struct:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    float X, Y, Z;
    float U, V;
};
```

Comment: Can you convert your code from screenshot to typed form please?

Comment: Why? It is perfectly fine in screenshot and will look exactly the same.

Comment: Except it will be visible in the question without clicking on the link, and it will be parseable with a search engine. Additionally, I don't know how long gyazo.com keeps images so this question may become useless quickly. Keep in mind, you're asking people to help you. You should desire to make that as easy as possible. Further, the question and answers are not just for you, they're for anyone who has a similar problem in the future.

Comment: It takes a few seconds to view the links and is a lot easier for me to upload things. My gyazo account holds images forever so no need to worry

Comment: There you go I editted it for you.

Comment: What about this one? http://gyazo.com/0422d4f37134671eb0b35c2a00605f7e Keep in mind you don't have to edit the question. My suggestion was only to help you get answers.

Comment: Okay and the shader code seems like to much to write in here really..

Comment: The images were removed but when they were there it looked to me like you just need to enable mipmapping which will make it look smoother when you are further away from the texture. If that isn't what you are talking about could you clarify the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue. The simple solution was changing the declaration in the TEXCOORD area I made it

```
         {
            0,
            sizeof(float) * 3,
            D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2,
            D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT,
            D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD,
            0
        },
```